# XSLT calling the value of the attribute from the xml

Tags: xml, xslt

i have this xml and im trying to display using xslt. i am able to display the date,and the team name, but i cannot get the value of the score to display.

```
<teamscores>
    <season year="2015">
        <game>  
            <date>20151004</date>
            <team1 score="77">MIA</team1>
            <team2 score="90">CHA</team2>
        </game>
```

```
<tr>
  <td>
    Date:
    <xsl:value-of select ="date"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select ="team1"/>   << this does display
    (<xsl:value-of select ="@score"/>) <<-- does not display.
  </td>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select ="team2"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the context at that point is `<game>`, the correct XPath expression is `team1/@score`, i.e.

```
(<xsl:value-of select ="team1/@score"/>)
```